# how to select the row id on button click event inside gridview

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have added the two button in my gridview..
where data gets loaded in grid view on page load event .. 
now i want to write the update and delete query on add and delete button respectively.
My question is how to select the row id on button click event

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="flat-table flat-table-1">
   <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Button ID="btn_add" runat="server" CommandName="Add" OnClick="btn_add_Click" Text="Add" CssClass="btn btn-align btn-primary" />
             <asp:Button ID="btn_cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" OnClick="btn_cancel_Click" Text="Delete" CssClass="btn btn-align btn-danger" />
        </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify `ItemTempalate` to following.Note: i have used `CommandArgument` to pass selected `row_index`.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btn_add" runat="server" CommandName="Add" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
            Text="Add" CssClass="btn btn-align btn-primary" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn_cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" Text="Delete" CssClass="btn btn-align btn-danger" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And add `row_command` event, and use following server side code , i have handled for `"Add"` operation only.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName == "Add")
    {
        // Handling for add
        string arg = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        int rowidx = int.Parse(arg);
        // arg = selected index, as we are using that in cmd arg.
        GridViewRow SelectedRow = GridView1.Rows[rowidx];
    }
}
```